# How can I tell which commits are included in merge?

Tags: git, merge

I merged branch develop into branch my-feature with the following command:

```
$ git merge --no-ff develop
```

I expected that afterwards my-feature branch would be ahead of origin/my-feature by two commits: the merge commit and the other that I wanted to bring in. However, `git status` reports that it's ahead by three commits:

```
$ git status
On branch my-feature
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/my-feature' by 3 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I'd like to figure out which commits were included in the merge without combing through the logs. Is there a command to list them or just list the commits that are "ahead"? I tried doing a hard reset and using `git merge --log`, thinking it would list them in the log message, but it only showed one commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
git log origin/my-feature..my-feature
```

to see the commits that are in your branch, but have not yet been pushed (the *ahead* commits).

Since you are already on `my-feature` though, you can shorten it to:

```
git log origin/my-feature..
```